# Displacement modifier causing bad seam

Tags: modifiers, uv-image-editor, displacement

Noobie here.
I am trying to use a Displacement modifier to emboss a ring. The modifier works except for an unintended displacement along one edge (yes, it is also the edge of the UV map). It seems to be related to the edge, but I don't understand what is different about it. It was originally assigned as a seam but I deleted the seam. There is nothing in the UV map that corresponds with the indent. What am I doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: Check if you have internal faces in that area.

Comment: Ok, I think "True" displacement maps in Cycles might be a better choice. I'll keep working.

Comment: Using the new cycles displacement can give you extra details in a rendered image without adding geometry - I am guessing you want to 3d print this and cycles displacement will not add detail to the printed object, for that you will need the extra real geometry that you will have after applying the modifiers. The glitch looks more like a geometry thing, an extra internal face and/or disconnected vertices. Most likely sharing your blend will allow someone to find the issue - uploading to [blend-exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) then add the link here is the preferred way.

Comment: Thanks to you both. I did end up using Cycles displacement and it worked fine. I DID suspect the geometry. I'll go back and try to find it based on your suggestions. Actually, no, I'm not planning to 3D print this particular image. Your heads-up though, is very helpful information.